# Firebase Swift 3 Fetching multiple values from a group

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, firebase, fetch

I want to be able to list users in a tableview by fetching their UID Value from a key stored in my database. As of now, the code only fetches the first value in the database rather than all of the values. Here is the code for fetching the applicants.

```
func loadApplicants() {
    let usersRef = ref.child("users")
    usersRef.observe(.value, with: { (users) in

        var resultArray = [UserClass]()

        for user in users.children {
            let user = UserClass(snapshot: user as! DataSnapshot)

            if user.uid == self.job.userID {
                let appRef = self.ref.child("jobs").child(self.job.postID).child("applicants")
                appRef.queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                    let sValue = snapshot.value
                    resultArray.append(user)
                })
            }
        }
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

This is what my database looks like where the User's UIDs are stored.

```
jobs
 "Job ID"
    applicants:
     -KtLJaQnFMnyI-MDWpys:"8R6ZAojX0FNO7aSd2mm5aQXQFpk1"
     -KtLLBFU_aVS_xfSpw1k:"GGqjtYvwSwQw9hQCVpF4lHN0kMI3"
```

If I was to run the app, it fetches UID: "8R6ZAojX0FNO7aSd2mm5aQXQFpk1"
How can I implement a for loop or an if statement to ensure that all of the values are taken and appended into the table view

I know that I need a for loop before the fetchApplicants is called from AuthService because it is only fetching one UID but I can't work out where it would go.

Thanks.

P.S. This is what I have tried

```
func loadApplicants() {
    let jobID = job.postID
    let appRef = ref.child("jobs").child(jobID!).child("applicants")
    appRef.queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let applicants = snapshot.value! as? [String:AnyObject] {
            for (value) in applicants {
                self.authService.fetchApplicants(applicantID: "\(value!)", completion: { (users) in
                    self.usersArray = users
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }
    })
}
```

but the output is:

```
(key: "-KtLLBFU_aVS_xfSpw1k", value: GGqjtYvwSwQw9hQCVpF4lHN0kMI3)
(key: "-KtLJaQnFMnyI-MDWpys", value: 8R6ZAojX0FNO7aSd2mm5aQXQFpk1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to use observe instead of observeSingleEvent

Answer:

```
appRef.queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
```